# Match contents of file to directory and delete it

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

Let's say I ran a command that redirected certain files from a directory into a file. Now i want to delete those files from the directory. How would i accomplish this. I'm thinking that i would maybe use a for loop and read each line of the file and then run a command to remove it? I don't need the whole code just a little help to get started. I would like to do this using bash.

Comment: Never mind. I would just run the same command and use rm or xargs rm . Sorry dumb question its still early .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar to for loop. that will list all files in ~/test. replace ls with rm

```
dir="$HOME/test"

while IFS= read -r file || [ "$file" ]
  do
    [ -f "$dir/$file" ] || continue
    ls "$dir/$file"
done < index.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. This worked for me